# Anti_join by pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, fuzzyjoin

Tibble `A` contains keys/patterns that may be found in tibble `B`. My goal is to identify keys/patterns that were not found in tibble `B`.

I want to anti-join two tables by a matching pattern:

```
A <- tibble( colA = c("B12", "B19", "B202", "B87", "B61", "B55") )
B <- tibble( colB = c("aaB87aa", "bbbbB55", "B202cccc") )
```

I found that function from `fuzzyjoin` should work but I can't use it properly:

```
test <- regex_anti_join(A, B, by = c(colB = "colA"))
```

**EDIT**

At the end I would like to have something like this:

```
test
1 B12
2 B19
3 B61
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: Looks like there is a pattern, maybe using regex extract id as "starts with B followed by digits until a letter", then use that id as join column.

Comment: Maybe so? `regex_anti_join(A, B, by = c(colA = "colB"))`

Comment: @YuriySaraykin it gives all `A` tibble as the output - it's not anti-join

Comment: Have you considered using `dplyr::filter()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex_anti_join(A, B, by = c(colA = colB))` performs a `str_detect` of `colB` inside `colA`. In your case this return nothing, hence the empty result.

What you need is to do the inverse: search `colA` inside `colB`.

This can be achieved specifying the matching function to the `fuzzy_join` function that is used by `regex_anti_join`:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

# This is exactly the inverse of the match_fun used inside regex_anti_join
match_fun <- function(v1, v2) {
  stringr::str_detect(v2, stringr::regex(v1))
}

fuzzy_join(A, B, by = c("colA" = "colB"), match_fun=match_fun, mode = 'anti')
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   colA 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 B12  
#> 2 B19  
#> 3 B61
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option given the example data could be:

```
A %>%
 filter(!colA %in% gsub("[a-z]", "", B$colB))

  colA 
  <chr>
1 B12  
2 B19  
3 B61
```